# React-Native unable to build project

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to implement the FB Auth and followed everything mentioned in [FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)  . React-native: 0.47.1   and FBSDK: 0.6.1
. After I did that, the project wont build. Getting error:

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

[image]

I checked that the `MainApplication.java` and `MainActivity.java` and have copied everything as mentioned in github page. I also ran `react-native link react-native-fbsdk` after i installed `react-native-fbsdk`. I restarted the laptop to be sure to have reset the gradle or anything cause its a windows laptop. I'm not sure why it's giving this error.

Please help. Many thanks.

After removing the following from `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBSDKPackage.java`

```
@Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

I tried to build the project again and getting error:

[image]

Comment: Which version of react-native and fbsdk are you using please ?

Comment: react-native: 0.47.1   and fbsdk: 0.6.1

Comment: What do you mean update the module manually? I'm sorry, I'm new to RN. Could you please elaborate? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a commun issue for react native 0.47 https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/354 and the fix is not released yet.

What you can do waiting for the next release is to go to the file :

> node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBSDKPackage.java

and remove the method and the @Override who cause this error line 61 to 64.

```
@Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Then rebuild your app

Comment: I did that and getting another error now. I updated my question and added the error.

Comment: any idea why its failing ?

Comment: @Somename theses erros are pretty clear, it looks like you have a syntax issue in your MainApplication.java certainly from the code you copy paste fom react native fbsdk.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo error. I fixed that. I created a new project from scratch and it failed with the error i mentioned in the edit in my question. The 2nd Image. I did remove the line 61-64 in this also.

Comment: I changed `protected` to `public` and it fixed it. Is there any harm in it?